# how to allow the user to change font Swift

Tags: swift, font-size

I am building an application that display details and i want to allow user to change font of these details 
I have done some researches but all of them were to go to device's settings and change the font from there
so, is there any way to have similar settings inside my application

Thank you in advance

***Update***

i used the following slider but it didnt works

```
@IBAction func FontSlider(sender: AnyObject) {
    var currentValue  = Int(Slider.value) as Int
    println(currentValue)
    ingredients.font = UIFont(name: ingredients.font.fontName, size: currentValue)

      }
```

Comment: How do you display these details to user? UILabel?

Comment: some of them are labels and the others are textview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the [appearance proxies](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/index.html) for UILabel and UITextView, and save the font in [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html).

When the user selects a font (You will have to create an interface, Rizwan's answer about using a UIPickerView is a good idea), you can save the font and set it for all labels and textViews.

```
func setDefaultFont (font: UIFont)
{
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(font, forKey: "defaultFont")

    UILabel.appearance().font = font;

    UITextView.appearance().font = font;
}
```

You might want to check for the saved font and set it. This can be called in the `-viewDidLoad` method of your root viewController or even in the app delegate.

```
func checkAndSetDefaultFont ()
{
    let font: UIFont = (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("defaultFont") as? UIFont)!

    UILabel.appearance().font = font;

    UILabel.appearance().font = font;
}
```

Comment: thank you for this, but actually i'm using Swift not Objective-C

Comment: Yeah... I'm converting this into swift... didn't notice the tag before.

Comment: @user3599431 The code examples have been converted into Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Better approach is used `UIPickerView` in which u  give the different `UIfont` option to user.

Once user select any option use  `didSelectRow` function  and change the font with respect to user selected font.

**Edit:** As u used slider than used as

```
@IBAction func FontSlider(sender: UISlider) {
var currentValue  = Int(Slider.value) as Int
println(currentValue)
ingredients.font = UIFont(name: ingredients.font.fontName, size: currentValue)

  }
```

Comment: i used slider but it didn't work it gives me error in the UIfont        @IBAction func FontSlider(sender: AnyObject) {
        
     
        var currentValue  = Int(Slider.value) as Int
        println(currentValue)
        ingredients.font = UIFont(name: ingredients.font.fontName, size: currentValue)

          }