# Is there a Cocoapod/Standard way that allows user to change the font size within the app like the one in iBooks app in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, font-size, dynamic-type-feature

I am trying to implement a font size changer functionality similar to the one provided by the iBooks app in iPhone.

I know how to set the font using Dynamic Type when Text Size changes at the phone level, but the requirement here is to allow the user to change the font size within the app, and update the content as per the new font size.
(I need to change the brightness and the font size only.)

I looked over the net and found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30638133/how-to-allow-the-user-to-change-font-swift)

This link shows a manual way of doing it. I was wondering if this a common requirement among apps and is there a standard way/cocoa pod to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe your requirement could be a bit more specific. Are you looking for just one text view or are there many or even all of them? Are you actually looking to apply some sort of scale like increase font size of all components by 1.5? Is your issue how to change size on each element or is it how to create a control to change size or is it how to find all components that need to change in size?

Comment: Sorry! Here are the details : 1. There is one textview  2. On the top of this textview, on the navbar, I will provide a "ᴀA" text formatter button, On clicking of it, a modal opens showing a slider - which lets the user increase the font size. On increasing the slider  (moving right) the content behind should increase in font and accordingly decrease if slider is moved to the left.
So my question is -  is there a library that provides this control to change the font size of components as and when needed.

Comment: What you have found has virtually nothing to do with your question; they never discuss any buttons or sliders.

There is no builtin menu for this in the UIKit (moreover, popovers are not natively supported on the iPhone), but I doubt that you need a "library" for setting a font size based on a slider input, it's around 10 lines of code maximum to be honest.

Comment: I agree, But they discuss how to update the font of the components.

Answer (score 0):

Been a Java developer for about 8 years, and was used to using the term "library" which I believe didn't make much sense in the iOS world.

I was looking for something that lets me change the font size and the screen brightness in one shot since I thought it would be a common requirement in most of the reading apps. Something like this :
[image]

Since I didn't find anything, and like @WTEDST mentioned saying it requires few lines of code, I went ahead and

1. Added a view(B) on top of my main view(A)
2. Showed this view(B) only on clicking of the ᴀA button
3. This view(B) contained the slider component and 2 buttons at the bottom for increasing and decreasing the font size.
4. I added a method to change screen brightness on moving the slider and another method on each of the increase/decrease font buttons.
5. Used a UIStackView to arrange the items nicely.

Done.